# SWFUpload upload script

Tags: php, javascript, file-upload, swfupload

I've been looking at the swfupload demos, I'm wondering is there an alternative to using the PHP script upload.php, i.e. using a JavaScript version.

Comment: You have to do something to the file when it reaches the server. JavaScript is client-side, you can't (and shouldn't) use it to manage the files on the server.

Comment: like @Juhana said you can't do it with Javascript, the only "ajaxy" option is [SWFUpload](http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/) it's your best option .. and is easy to install and easy to use.

Comment: Thanks All for comments and answers, I'll go with a serverside scripting language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something running on your server that will accept the uploaded file from the browser and then do something with it, like saving it to directory. 
PHP is a server-side language which can do this, however, javascript runs in your browser, not on the server, so doesn't have access to save files to the server.
It's likely that you have some sort scripting language running on your server, so it should technically be possible. Perhaps asp? cgi? perl?

Answer (score 1):

try http://www.uploadify.com/

still use swf; but in background mode, ( swf doesn't appears on your html ) and yours methods/callbacks are 100% javascript;